Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]
I am running WSL v2 under windows 11.  I want to start pytorch and profit from my RTX-4080 inside a docker container.  I want to run whisper, celery, redis and fastapi stack in the long run.
Nvidia describes the process to start a docker container running PyTorch, with these versions of Docker images.
I run the following command to run the docker image v24.09:
docker run --gpus all -it --rm nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:24.09-py3

I get this error :
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].

I tried with another example found on internet but the result is similar. Here is the command line :
docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark

[sudo] password for wsluser: 
Unable to find image 'nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody' locally
nbody: Pulling from nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample
22c5ef60a68e: Pull complete 
1939e4248814: Pull complete 
548afb82c856: Pull complete 
a424d45fd86f: Pull complete 
207b64ab7ce6: Pull complete 
f65423f1b49b: Pull complete 
2b60900a3ea5: Pull complete 
e9bff09d04df: Pull complete 
edc14edf1b04: Pull complete 
1f37f461c076: Pull complete 
9026fb14bf88: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:59261e419d6d48a772aad5bb213f9f1588fcdb042b115ceb7166c89a51f03363
Status: Downloaded newer image for nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: 
      - path: ./.env
        required: true # default
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - /tmp:/tmp
    depends_on:
      - celery
      - redis
    command: uvicorn src.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: 
      - path: ./.env
        required: true # default  
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ${HOME}/.cache/whisper:/root/.cache/whisper
      - /tmp:/tmp
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: celery -A src.tasks worker --loglevel=info -E

  redis:
    env_file: 
      - path: ./.env
        required: true # default
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"


  flower:
    build: .
    env_file: 
      - path: ./.env
        required: true # default
    command: celery -A src.tasks flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    depends_on:
      - redis

Dockerfile that does not yes use the nvidia image:
# Use the official Python base image
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Expose the necessary ports
EXPOSE 5555 8000 6379

# Install the dependencies
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y ffmpeg net-tools &&  \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Create the appuser with the home directory /app
RUN useradd -m -d /app appuser

# Ensure the home directory for 'appuser' has the correct permissions
RUN mkdir -p /app/.cache/whisper && \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /app

# Copy the FastAPI code to the container
COPY . .

# Switch to the appuser
USER appuser

# Set the working directory explicitly
WORKDIR /app

# Command to run your application (add as needed)
# CMD ["python", "main.py"]  # Replace with your actual start command

nvidia-smi result:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.02              Driver Version: 560.94         CUDA Version: 12.6     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080        On  |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   44C    P0             51W /  320W |    3429MiB /  16376MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        25      G   /Xwayland                                   N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


It seems like, independent of any of your application code, just docker run the NVidia-provided PyTorch image doesn't work.  Is the Compose file you're including here used at all?

@DavidMaze I don't know what you meant but indeed the content of the image lacked few tools. I have added them into the answer.
nevertheless, the docker image DOES still NOT recognize my GPU :-(

The solution: use another image provided by nvidia
.env file
CELERY_BROKER_URL = redis://redis:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = redis://redis:6379/0
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_RETRY_ON_STARTUP = True

FLOWER_UNAUTHENTICATED_API=true

# To allow access to all GPUs
NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all 
NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility
TORCH_WEIGHTS_ONLY=true

Dockerfile-cuda
# Use the official Python base image
#FROM python:3.11-slim
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:24.09-py3


# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Expose the necessary ports
EXPOSE 5555 8000 6379

# Install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    ffmpeg \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    ca-certificates \
    lsb-release \
    sudo

# Add NVIDIA Container Toolkit GPG key
RUN curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg

# Add NVIDIA Container Toolkit repository
RUN curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/deb/nvidia-container-toolkit.list | \
    sed 's#deb https://#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://#g' | \
    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

# Install the dependencies
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y ffmpeg net-tools
    
RUN apt install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
RUN apt install -y nvidia-driver-560
    
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Create the appuser with the home directory /app
RUN useradd -m -d /app appuser

# Ensure the home directory for 'appuser' has the correct permissions
RUN mkdir -p /app/.cache/whisper && \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /app

# Copy the FastAPI code to the container
COPY . .

# Switch to the appuser
# USER appuser

# Set the working directory explicitly
WORKDIR /app

# Command to run your application (add as needed)
# CMD ["python", "main.py"]  # Replace with your actual start command

requirements.txt
fastapi
celery
redis[hiredis]
uvicorn
flower
python-dotenv
openai-whisper
python-multipart


# install pytorch based on pytorch.org
# pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124
torch 
torchvision 
torchaudio 
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

